# maxima minima optimization problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

My problem is

Find  the greatest and least distance of the surface $6x^2+4xy+3y^2+14z^2=14$
from the origin.

I know that mathematical model of problem is $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to 
$g(x,y,z)=6x^2+4xy+3y^2+14z^2-14$

I tried to obtain the critical point and i got it as $(0,0,\pm 1)$ Is this correct. if it is correct then maxima and minima are same. Can both occur at the same place?

Comment: Could you show us how you got there?

Answer (score 1):

here is a different way to get answer which could help you to find some critical points:

$6x^2+4xy+3y^2=4x^2+2(x+y)^2+y^2 \ge 0 \implies 14 \ge 14z^2 \implies z^2 \le 1$

$-((2x)^2+y^2) \le 4xy \le x^2+(2y)^2 \implies 2x^2+2y^2 \le 6x^2+4xy+3y^2 \le 7x^2+7y^2  \implies 2-z^2 \le x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 7-6z^2 $

$2-z^2 \ge 1,7-6z^2 \le 7 $

so you get  min points but miss max points.